# Online Literature/Resources | ~ Calculus level

Tags: soft-question

just a quick ask for recommendations:

I'm a lonely math enthusiast, and my current knowledge goes to a half "mastery" of Calculus 1-3. And a bit of L.A. and discrete mathematics at that. And I've mainly used resources such as Khan Academy and various textbooks that I've come across:

Doesn't matter if it's books, videos or whatever if you're wondering.

More specific: Differtial Equations (Preferably in higher dimensions) and's applications would be of greatest interest. Don't really know to much about it, but just somewhere to start.

Also, google play... Is it any point in looking there? It's the most convenient way if there's a paywall.

Sorry for a kind of long text, but I'd appreciate any help :-). Should you have another course, just say it. Someone else may have use for it...

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is far too open ended for this site. Trying narrowing your question to a specific subject of math, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Areas_of_mathematics Just start clicking links and reading stuff. If you find it interesting, ask about those subjects. Just filter out the scary symbols, because wikipedia can be super technical at times

Comment: @JonathanDavidson Sorry for that, I've edited it to narrow it down. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Any subject that requires analysis with multiple dimensions requires a knowledge of linear algebra. I recommend using linear algebra as a starting place for your journey into higher mathematics. Moreover, try MIT OpenCourseWare for free mit classes on these subjects.

Comment: @JonathanDavidson Sorry forgot to add that I've got a reasonable amount of experience with L.A.

Comment: Do some group theory and lie algebras. Matrices give alot of examples for group theory and abstract algebras. Also, probability theory when mixed with any branch of mathematics is pretty cool. For example look up Erdos-Renyi graphs, a type of random graph that has interesting properties

Comment: If you know some linear algebra you can probably learn some algebraic topology (for spaces built out of simplices, so you can avoid point set topology problems, and just think combinatorially)... I'm not sure what textbook would cover this though.

Comment: I also like Abbot's understanding analysis, if you want to understand calculus more deeply. (It's challenging though.)